# Using /dev/stdin and a heredoc to pass a file from the command line

Tags: bash, command-line, here-document, ansible

I'm curious about the theory behind how heredocs can be passed as a file to a command line utility.

Recently, I discovered I can pass a file as heredoc.

For example:

```
awk '{ split($0, arr, " "); print arr[2] }' <<EOF
foo bar baz
EOF
bar
```

This is advantageous for me for several reasons:

- Heredocs improve readability for multi line inputs.
- I don't need to memorize each utilities flag for passing the file contents from the command line.
- I can use single and double quotes in the given files.
- I can control shell expansion.

For example:

```
ruby <<EOF
puts "'hello $HOME'"
EOF
'hello /Users/mbigras'

ruby <<'EOF'
puts "'hello $HOME'"
EOF
'hello $HOME'
```

I'm not clear what is happening.
It seems like the shell thinks the heredoc is a file with contents equal to the value of the heredoc.
I've this technique used with cat, but I'm still not sure what was going on:

```
cat <<EOL
hello world
EOL
hello world
```

I know `cat` prints the contents of a file, so presumably this heredoc is a temporary file of some kind.

I'm confused about what precisely is going on when I "pass a heredoc to a command line program".

Here's an example using [ansible-playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-playbook.html).
I pass the utility a playbook as a heredoc; however it fails, as shown using `echo $?`:

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local <<EOF &>/dev/null
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Print something
      debug:
        msg: hello world
EOF
echo $?
5
```

However, if I pass the utility the same heredoc but preceed it with `/dev/stdin` it succeeds

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local /dev/stdin <<EOF &>/dev/null
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Print something
      debug:
        msg: hello world
EOF
echo $?
0
```

- What precisly is going on when one "passes a heredoc as a file"?
- Why does the first version with `ansible-playbook` fail but second version succeed?
- What is the significance of passing `/dev/stdin` before the heredoc?
- Why do other utilities like `ruby` or `awk` not need the `/dev/stdin` before the heredoc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What precisely is going on when one "passes a heredoc as a file"?

You aren't. [Here-documents provide standard input,](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) like a pipe. Your example

```
awk '{ ... }' <<EOF
foo bar baz
EOF
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
echo foo bar baz | awk '{ ... }'
```

`awk`, `cat`, and `ruby` all read from standard input if they aren't given a filename to read from on the command line. That is an implementation choice.

> Why does the first version with anisble-playbook fail but second version succeed?

`ansible-playbook` does not read from standard input by default, but requires a file path instead. This is a design choice.

`/dev/stdin` is quite likely a symlink to `/dev/fd/0`, which is a way of talking about the current process's [file descriptor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_166) #0 (standard input). That's something exposed by your kernel (or system library). The `ansible-playbook` command opens `/dev/stdin` like a regular filesystem file and ends up reading its own standard input, which would otherwise have been ignored.

You likely also have `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` links to FDs 1 & 2, which you can use as well if you're telling something where to put its output.

> What is the significance of passing /dev/stdin before the heredoc?

It is an argument to the `ansible-playbook` command.

> Why do other utilities like ruby or awk not need the /dev/stdin before the heredoc?

They read from standard input by default as a design choice, because they are made to be used in pipelines. They write to standard output for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

A here-document is a redirection into the standard input of a command, just like `<`.  This means that anywhere where you may use `<` to redirect contents from a file, you may instead redirect the contents of a here-document.  The POSIX standard [lists here-documents along with the other redirection operators](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04).

In your Ansible example, `ansible-playbook` does not by default read from its standard input stream as it expects a filename.  By giving it `/dev/stdin` as the filename and then supplying the here-document on standard input, you bypass this restriction in the utility. The `/dev/stdin` "file" will always contain the standard input data stream of the current process.

`ruby` and `awk` as well as many other utilities will read from standard input *unless* a filename is supplied on the command line.

So, you are *technically* wrong when you say "It seems like the shell thinks the heredoc is a file with contents equal to the value of the heredoc". It does not act like a file (with regards to having a filename and being seekable), but as a data stream on standard input. At least from the point of view of the utility.

The difference is the same as between

```
cat file
```

and

```
cat <file
```

In the first instance, `cat` opens the file `file`, but in the second (which is also what happens with a here-document), since no filename was given as an argument to `cat`, `cat` just reads its standard input stream (and the *shell* opens the file, or provides the here-document, on standard input to the utility). The utility does not need to know if the provided data comes from a file, a pipe, a here-document or some other data source.

How here-documents are implemented by the shell is in a way unimportant, but it may be through the use of a FIFO or indeed with a temporary file.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly is going on with here-docs is depending on how  shell implements here-doc: it may be either done with pipes internally as in case of `dash` or with temporary file descriptor, as in `bash`. So in one case it may not be possible to `lseek()`, but in the other - it can be (which for average user it means you can jump around the contents of the here-doc). See [related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337750/85039).

As for the case of two ansible-playbook commands, it also depends on how command is implemented (so unless you read source code you won't actually know). Some commands simply check whether or not there is a file provided, and don't support `stdin`. Other commands like `awk` and `ruby` - they are designed to expect `stdin` or a file specified on command-line.

What you can try doing, however, is if you're using Linux, run `strace ansible-playbook ...<other args>` and see what things it tries to open, what syscalls occur, etc. For example, you'll see that with `strace -e open tail /dev/stdin  <<< "Jello World"` the tail command will actually try to open `/dev/stdin` as file, whereas `trace -e open tail` doesn't.