# How to run `go run` against inline code

Tags: bash, shell, golang

I have this mini bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

go run <(cat <<EOF
package main

import "log"

func main(){
  log.Println("here 123")
}
EOF
)
```

`go run` takes a file path argument, often times just something like:

```
go run main.go
```

is there a way to fool go into running my inline program? I am currently getting this error:

> package /dev/fd/63: import "/dev/fd/63": cannot import absolute path

Comment: This might help you [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425281/245871)

Comment: I wonder what exactly you are trying to achieve?  Why are you running a inline program from bash script?  Could you share with us the workflow?

Answer (score 3):

Like all high-brow tools and languages, `go` is not easily amenable to be used in ways its authors did not like or foresee.

In this case, `go` does not want to have anything to do with with paths not ending in `*.go`.

A solution may be to use a temporary file named `*.go`:

```
gorun(){
  t=$(mktemp -d) && cat > "$t/in.go" && go run "$t/in.go"
  e=$?; rm -fr "$t"; return "$e"
}

gorun <<'EOT'
...
EOT
```

I cannot use just `mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXX.go` above; that will silently create a file named exactly `/tmp/XXXXXXX.go` on BSD, where `mktemp` only supports trailing `Xs`. Also, I cannot assume that `/tmp` exists, is writable and is the place where temporary files are created by default.

---

This point is already moot, but `go` also has problems with pipes and other non-regular files, so a process substitution wouldn't have worked anyway:

```
% ln -s /dev/fd/3 fd3.go
% go run fd3.go 3<<<'package main; func main(){}'
  // OK
% go run fd3.go 3< <(echo 'package main; func main(){}')
# command-line-arguments
./fd3.go:1:1: syntax error: package statement must be first
% cat fd3.go 3< <(echo 'package main; func main(){}')
package main; func main(){}
  // WTF?
% mkfifo fifo.go
% go run fifo.go &
[1] 8849
% echo 'package main; import "log"; func main(){log.Println("yuck!")}' > fifo.go
   // if at first you don't succeed ...
% echo 'package main; import "log"; func main(){log.Println("yuck!")}' > fifo.go
% 2020/02/06 11:21:53 yuck!

[1]+  Done                    go run fifo.go
```

Comment: yeah a short inline program is nice sometimes, don't have to wonder what it does, it's right there

Comment: You can give `mktemp` a "template", like `mktemp XXXXXX.go` creates something like `nVF1Ja.go`. That should clean up your function a bit.

Comment: @glennjackman no, I cannot assume that the current working dir is writable, that mktemp supports non-trailing XXXs or that `/tmp` exists, is writable and is the place where tempfiles are created by default. Or that mktemp supports the TMPDIR envvar. But that `mv` was subject to a symlink attack, thanks for making me rethink it ;-)

Comment: @glennjackman I haven't make up that stuff for the sake of the argument: `mktemp XXXXXX.go` will create a file named exactly `XXXXXX.go` on FreeBSD, there's no `/tmp` on Android and `/tmp` is not the default tmpdir on MacOS. And dropping stuff inside cwd or the homedir is gross, even if it may work.