# Reading a literal from stdin- Ambiguous redirect error when using EOF

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to read a string literal into stdin using the following method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;

gmx --stdin < `cat <<EOF
   node e "console.log('foo')"
EOF`
```

when I run this, I get this error:

```
simple.sh: line 5: `cat <<EOF
   node e "console.log('foo')"
EOF`: ambiguous redirect
```

If I get rid of the backticks,

```
 gmx --stdin < cat <<EOF
       node e "console.log('foo')"
 EOF
```

I get this error:

```
/simple.sh: line 5: cat: No such file or directory
```

anyone know how to fix? If it's unclear what I am trying to do - I am just trying to read a string literal into the stdin of the gmx process.

I also tried this:

```
gmx --stdin <<<  node e "console.log('foo')"
```

but that didn't seem to work, I might need to put the node command in quotes, which sort defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do. I am looking to include shell variables in the command - HEREDOC is nice because I don't need to escape " characters.

Answer (score 1):

**Original**:

`<` needs files or file descriptors, while you have command-substitution there, which replaces whatever backticks are with a string of text.

For your purpose you might be better off using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) in `bash`.  Something like this:

```
gmx --stdin < <(node e "console.log('foo')")
```

Or another example for clarity:

```
wc -l < <(df)
```

**Edit**:

To pass string literal that represents the command, you may use:

```
gmx --stdin <<< "$(echo node -e $'"console.log(\'foo\')"' )"
```

the `$'...'` allows for C-quoting , which is what `\'foo\'` part does.

Here's basically same example, but with pipe instead (which may not work if a command requires a [lseekable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337739/85039) input)

```
$ touch with\ space
$ echo stat $'\'with space\''
stat 'with space'
$ echo stat $'\'with space\'' | sh
  File: with space
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 1069455     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/     xie)   Gid: ( 1000/     xie)
Access: 2018-05-07 05:01:37.638553045 +0800
Modify: 2018-05-07 05:01:37.638553045 +0800
Change: 2018-05-07 05:01:37.638553045 +0800
 Birth: -
```

Additionally, there is a way to deal with quoting via `printf %q`, which from `help printf` is described as:

> quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input

So potential solution is

```
printf '%q'  'node -e "conlose.log('foo')"' | gmx --stdin
```

or

```
gmx --stdin <<< "$( printf '%q'  'node -e "conlose.log('foo')"' )"
```

Comment: thanks I suspected that, can you show an example of process substitution for this case?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Added an example of that, plus extra one for clarity

Comment: Yeah, I think you might have missed what I am looking for - I am trying to send a string literal respresenting the node command to gmx stdin, not pass the stdout from the node command to the stdin of the gmx. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: To explain further, the gmx command will run the string literal in a subshell, so I need to pass the literal string 'node -e "console.log('foo');"' to the gmx stdin

Comment: This works: `cat <<< "echo "444""` the problem is that I have to surround the echo command with double quotes, I am looking to avoid that so I don't have to escape the double quotes. Heredoc would allow me to avoid, but now sure how to do it.

Comment: @AlexanderMills  So, you wanted to basically  you want to `echo node -e $'"console.log(\'foo\')"'` and pass it to `gmx --stdin` ? Try that with pipe,  `echo node -e $'"console.log(\'foo\')"' |  gmx --stdin` . Alternatively,  `gmx --stdin <<< "$(echo node -e $'"console.log(\'foo\')"'  )"`

Comment: @AlexanderMills I've edited the answer, hopefully that helps

Comment: I added an answer, I think using HEREDOC is much easier to use in mose cases

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, all I needed to do, was do this:

```
gmx --stdin <<EOF
   node e "console.log('foo')"
EOF
```

that would read the line starting with `node` as a string literal into the stdin of the gmx command.