# What’s the difference between providing input to a command via an argument to that command and providing input through a shell redirection operator?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, arguments, error-handling

When I use my shell’s redirection operator to provide a (non-existent) 
filename to the `grep` command, the error message about that file not
existing is displayed by my shell.  But when I provide that same filename 
as an argument to the `grep` command, the corresponding error message is
displayed by the `grep` command itself. Why is that?

Here’s a demonstration of what I’m talking about. When I run the command:

```
$ grep 'root' /etc/passw
```

I get the following error message:

> `grep: /etc/passw: No such file or directory`

But when I run the command this way with shell redirection:

```
$ grep 'root' < /etc/passw
```

I instead get the following error message:

> `bash: /etc/passw: No such file or directory`

What is the difference between these two methods of specifying the input 
filename, and is there any significance in having them behave this way?

Comment: The redirection is done by bash so it makes sense that bash errors in that case.  Otherwise `grep` itself tries to read from the file.  The way that the two differ varies from utility to utility.

Comment: @jesse_b Hi, thank you for your answer. I assumed it would be the case, is there any significant difference between the two ways of providing input?

Comment: @FuRinKaZan_001: For some things (like `wc`) there is a significant difference, I'm sure there are more examples as well I just can't think of them right now.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337739/117549

Comment: Similar: [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756)

Answer (score 1):

In your first command (`$ grep 'root' /etc/passw`) you give argument/s to `grep` and it interprets it as file name and searches for it. It (`grep`) fails so communicates you what happened. It is grep that interprets your input and acts on it.

In your second command (`grep 'root' < /etc/passw`) you make shell (here: `bash`) to pipe `/etc/passw` to standard input of `grep`. It (`bash`) cannot find it so it communicates you that. Here, it is bash that interprets your input and acts on it.

Second command is conceptual equivalent to `$ bash-cat /etc/passw | grep 'root'` where `bash-cat` would operate as `cat` which prints given file on standard output. Then it would be redirected to `grep`.

```
$ bash-cat /etc/passw | grep 'root'
```

> bash-cat: /etc/passw: No such file or directory

--

If you read about pipes you will understand. ([Pipes: A Brief Introduction](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html))

Comment: "Second command is conceptual equivalent to `$ bash-cat /etc/passw | grep 'root'`" – Only in the context of opening the file, but not further. I mean in `<passwd grep …` the tool starts with its stdin redirected to a regular file. It can seek if it wants. In Linux it can open the same file for writing (by opening `/dev/stdin`). It can know the size of the file. There is nothing between `grep` and `passwd`, the shell does not act as a relay. Your `bash-cat` is a "relay", your `grep` reads from an unnamed pipe, it cannot do these things I mentioned.

Comment: Maybe I overexplained this and made a mistake on the way. Maybe I should write an answer again, I simplests, possible way.

Answer (score 0):

When using I/O redirection operators like this, the shell itself opens the file for the input to the command as stdin with O_RDONLY on fd0 which commands can read only from it, but when passing as an argument, it’s the command itself which handles opening the file.

So if you have a program — let's say `awk` — and use `<` redirection to pass the filename, and you try to print `FILENAME` for which file it's opened, it will get reported `-` (meaning that input is stdin); see the following output:

```
awk '{ print FILENAME }' --infile
--infile

awk '{ print FILENAME }' <--infile
-
```

Another advantage is that if a filename starts with a hyphen, the shell will handle it itself, but if you pass as an argument to the command — say `grep` — it will complain because it think it's an invalid option provided.

```
grep root --infile
grep: unrecognized option '--infile'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Standard, standards-compliant commands use `--` to avoid this error by telling the command it’s the end of its option-argument.  You can also provide either the absolute path of file or a relative path with `./--infle`, or you let the shell open it for the command by using `command <--infile`.

note: Use of `<inputfile command` is the same variant of the `command <inputfile`.

another advantage is if that file was not exist or shell failed to open it, then your command will not execute.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "ifrun" }' < non-existing_file
-bash: non-existing_file: No such file or directory

awk 'BEGIN{ print "ifrun" }' non-existing_file
ifrun
```

Comment: Standard compliant `grep`s have no problem with `grep foo --infile`. Like standard compliant `awk`'s have no problem with `awk 1 --infile`. GNU `grep` does though when `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment, and some versions of busybox `awk` do. A file called `-` is also a problem whether `--` is used or not.